# anchored vwap doesn't start plotting at condition

Tags: pine-script

////////// what am I doing wrong here, when plotting the anchored vwap it is accurate but does not start at the condition highIndex, it runs continuous.  I'm a beginner of course ////////////////

```
src = input(hlc3)
lookback = input(50, title="Look Back")
highIndex = -highestbars(high, lookback)
t = time[highIndex]

start = t == time

sumSrc = src * volume
sumVol = volume
sumSrc := start ? sumSrc : sumSrc + sumSrc[1]
sumVol := start ? sumVol : sumVol + sumVol[1]

plot(sumSrc / sumVol, title="AVWAP", color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Every time there's a new highest high in the lookback window, it will trigger a new start. The previous vwaps aren't erased because they were correct at the time they were the current bar.

Comment: I see that.  I only want to plot the vwap from the last anchor so I thought I would try barssince() and apply it to the show_last in the plot function but I get an error on the plot function saying Cannot call 'plot' with 'show_last'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: input integer.  How could I use the barssince() as the show_last

Comment: Unfortunately `show_last` can only accept a literal int (ie 5) or an input int (ie `x = input(5)` / `show_last = x`). It's possible to do what you want, but it is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to plot only the most recent AVWAP you have to be able to remove the previous historical AVWAP as a new one is formed. It can be done by using the line functions as they can be deleted. You have to be aware of the line limit though. The max available per script is 500. If your AVWAP(s) line count exceeds this you will lose the oldest line segments on the screen.

```
//@version=4
study("Recent HH AVWAP", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)
hhlb = input(50)

f_vwap(_src, _volume, _new_interval) =>
    float _pvsum = na
    float _vsum = na
    _pvsum := _new_interval ? _src * _volume : _pvsum[1] + _src * _volume
    _vsum := _new_interval ? _volume : _vsum[1] + _volume
    _pvsum / _vsum

hh = highest(high, hhlb)


newhh = high > hh[1]
hh_vwap = f_vwap(hlc3, volume, newhh)

var line[] hh_lines = array.new_line(0)

if newhh and array.size(hh_lines) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(hh_lines) - 1
        temp = array.get(hh_lines, i)
        line.delete(temp)
    array.clear(hh_lines)
else if not newhh
    array.unshift(hh_lines, line.new(x1 = bar_index - 1, y1 = hh_vwap[1], x2 = bar_index, y2 = hh_vwap, color = color.red, width = 1))

if array.size(hh_lines) > 500
    temp = array.get(hh_lines, 500)
    line.delete(temp)
    array.pop(hh_lines)

var hh_size_label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = hh_vwap, style = label.style_label_left, color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 100), text = tostring(array.size(hh_lines)), textcolor = color.yellow, size = size.small)
label.set_xy(hh_size_label, x = bar_index, y = hh_vwap)
label.set_text(hh_size_label, text = tostring(array.size(hh_lines)))
```